# How do I add a link to a page using TypeScript? I'm stuck on how to do it. I've tried one method, but it's not working

Tags: html, jsx

```
  `<CommandItem><a href="@/src/app/page.tsx">Моя статистика</a></CommandItem>`
```

I tried it and it didn't work. I tried different methods on stackoverflow and they also didn't help.
I also tried doing it on the localhost but it didn't work (there).

Comment: From the syntax of your code, it seems like you are talking about Next.js, you should read [How to create route](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/defining-routes#creating-routes) and use [<Link />](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/link) instead of regular `<a>` tag. However, I encourage you to walk through some tutorials since these are just the basics of Next.js, more to come.

Answer (score -1):

Try this method,

```
let commandItem = '<CommandItem><a href="@/src/app/page.tsx">Моя статистика</a></CommandItem>';

let newHref = 'https://example.com'; // Replace this with your link

commandItem = commandItem.replace(/href="[^"]*"/, `href="${newHref}"`);

console.log(commandItem);
```